# How do I get a Light's Range value in Shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg, shaderlab

I'm trying to write a simple frag/vert shader that, depending on whether it is in the range of a light, will paint the appropriate colour from either the 'lit' texture or from the 'unlit' texture.

Therefore, I need to compare the distance between the light to the range of the light. 
I've been googling all kinds of things, but I can't seem to find a way of accessing the range value of the light. Is there a way to do so? If not, is there some kind of derived data I could use as an alternative?

**Update**

I was able to find this method [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/get-the-range-of-a-point-light-in-forward-add-mode.213430/#post-1433291), which seems to be the most promising so far, however after playing around for a bit, I still can't seem to get what I need. There's some talk about `_LightMatrix0` not being populated. Can anyone confirm?

**Update 2**

I found the variable `unity_LightAtten` in the [Unity Shader Variables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-UnityShaderVariables.html) documentation. However, this is only used for Vertex Lit shading, which isn't exactly ideal, especially considering the lack of console support.
Could there be a way to pipe this variable to Forward Rendering?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass [Light.range](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Light-range.html) into the shader using [Material.SetFloat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloat.html). You need to attach a script to do that.

Comment: ohh, promising...I'll have a stab and get back to here, thanks! but how would I distinguish between different lights?

Comment: Use different names for your lights. Then find those gameObjects by name in the script. [GameObject.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)

Comment: That's the first solution I reached for, but how would you know which light is being used in the current Pass in the Shader?

Comment: I suppose you could use the position instead of the name as the key (as that is accessible) but that just feels clumsy and expensive for lots of lights...

Comment: Sure if positions of lights doesn't change. Binding a shader to the game logic is alway expensive if you change the property every frame.

Comment: You can also try mapping the positions of the lights into a texture and sample from it in the shader.